# ClassNotFoundException with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I know this question has been asked a lot of time but I never found a working answer for me.

I have a problem with this line, saying the usual ClassNotFoundException.

> Unhandled exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

And in the console :

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:xxxxxxxxx

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

But I included the jar (*mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar*) in my project setups, I put it also in all my lib directories in my java installation (JRE and JDK).

Here is more code :
public class connection implements Listener{

```
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql:xxxxxxxxx";

static final String USER = "xxxxxx";
static final String PASS = "xxxxxx";

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Players (UUID, Pseudo, Rank, Level, Current_xp, Nbr_kick, Nbr_ban) VALUES (" + p.getUniqueId() + ", " + p.getName() + ", Dev, 1, 0, 0, 0);";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException se)
    {
        getLogger().warning(se.toString());
    }
}
```

here are my classphaths : [The classpath of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syUk1.png)

***EDIT :***

Ok, it works, and here is how : I used the following code (not mine) and after few corrections, it worked (don't be like me, don't forget the two slashes in *jdbc:mysql://xxxx:3306/xxxx*

```
System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException es) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        es.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxxx:3306/xxxx", USER, PASS);

    } catch (SQLException es) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        es.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
```

Comment: can you share more code please?

Comment: @YCF_L Done :) I hope this helps

Comment: also the error please the full error i forgot that sorry

Comment: The reason is simple. The library is not on the **runtime** classpath. Now instead of randomly putting the library in places it shouldn't be (like the JRE and JDK directories), stop and plan your moves carefully. Seems like you need to understand what the classpath is first, not just try random answers you find.

Comment: @Kayaman : I put an image of my classpaths, what am-i doing wrong in it ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add mysql driver dependency into maven or gradle(if you use maven or gradle project), or download jar file from this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) and add it into classpath of your project. It has to work. If not - you are doing something incorrect.

Comment: I tried with the file you gave me, and it didn't work either... I don't know what to do... It's in the project, but unseen...

Comment: [Do like here - must work](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)

Comment: MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for  jdbc:mysql:sql11.freexxxxx:3306/xxxxx

So close !! :(

Comment: If driver registered and connection failed - try to check your DB credentials.

Comment: It works !! Thank you ! I'll edit my message to explain how. Thank you so much !

Comment: Bingo:) My pleasure!